# How to make a simple Format Conversion Script?

Tags: python, scripting, import, conversion

I am a newbie in Blender and have only basic knowledge of Python scripting.
But I thought I could make this script on my own - but failed.

My basic idea is to import the file with `bpy.ops.import_scene.obj` and then export it:

```
import bpy
bpy.ops.import_mesh.stl (filepath = "C: // ...."
bpy.ops.export_scene.x3d (filepath = "C: // ..."
```

Here is my question:

How can I write a script where I can choose a file and dont have to use the same filepath and filename?

My problem is, the script should start in such a way that Blender should only be opened in the background and should not be visible. Is there a solution, with which I can specify a path in the console, without always taking the same path and file name for the file to be converted?

Comment: Hi. Seeing as we're dealing with code, I suggest showing the code you tried, in the question, then we can deal with specifically where it went wrong. At the minute the question is quite broad.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply! It is the absolute basic version:
import bpy
bpy.ops.import_mesh.stl (filepath = "C: // ...."
bpy.ops.export_scene.x3d (filepath = "C: // ..."


My problem is, the script should start in such a way that Blender should only be opened in the background and should not be visible. Is there a solution, with which I can specify a path in the console, without always taking the same path and file name for the file to be converted?
Thank you in advance!